# dev/input event how to determine which is my laptop's keyboard or mouse?

Tags: udev, input-devices

Having list of dev/input events, how to determine which is my laptop's keyboard or mouse?

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     100 Aug 29  2023 by-id
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     180 Aug 29  2023 by-path
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 64 Aug 29  2023 event0
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 65 Aug 29  2023 event1
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 66 Aug 29  2023 event2
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 67 Aug 29  2023 event3
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 68 Aug 29  2023 event4
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 69 Aug 29  2023 event5
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 70 Aug 29  2023 event6
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 71 Aug 29  2023 event7
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 72 Aug 29  2023 event8
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 73 Aug 29  2023 event9
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 63 Aug 29  2023 mice
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 32 Aug 29  2023 mouse0
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 33 Aug 29  2023 mouse1
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 34 Aug 29  2023 mouse2

supernova@supernova-BOHB-WAX9:~/Downloads/libevdev-master$ xinput list
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: You may look at the listing of `ls -l /dev/input/by-path`.